# Get URL with an if statement PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get URL path and to save it as variable...

```
$setURL = true;
$getDomain = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$getSubdomain = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($setURL === true) {
    $result = 'http://'.parse_url($getDomain, PHP_URL_HOST) . '/';
    echo 'get domain';
} else {
    $result = 'http://'.parse_url($getSubdomain, PHP_URL_HOST).parse_url($getSubdomain, PHP_URL_PATH);
    echo 'get subdomain';
}

$siteURL = $result;
```

So basically if I defined variable $setURL = true; it will return correct URL for simple domain ... http://domain-name.com

However else does not work as I want to... else is there for subdomains. So if I set $setURL = false; it should return following... http://domain-name.com/path/

But unfortunately it return more then that... It returns anything I type as URL...
http://domain-name.com/path/something/index.php it will return all of that as URL!

Please help me to fix this as I don't have any ideas how I could manage to make it.

Comment: what on earth is that if check even for? `$setURL` will never be false.

Comment: $setURL will be false if user define it... true/false it's users choice.

Comment: @user1658136 Not according to the code you have. You explicitly set `$setURL = true;`

Comment: but it will never be false if you set it right before the check. Also, your title barely makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, a **subdomain** precedes a domain name. For example, in `ftp.debian.us`, **ftp** is the subdomain.

It sounds like what you want is the first path in the URI. You can use PHP's explode() method to grab the first segment in the path.

```
$uriparts = explode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) // = '/path/to/somewhere/index.html'
$path = $uriparts[1] // = 'path'
```